# Missing prompt in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand a Python code example from a book. It's shown like this:

```
>>> 2 + 2
4
```

The book, and several other sources I've checked (including here) insist those chevrons (`>>>`) are just prompts for where I should type my expression, and not actually typed. However, whether or not I type the `>>>`, I don't see any output unless I also use `print`, which to my understanding should not be necessary.

I don't see the chevrons in most environments I've tried using, including Mu, PyCharm and Visual Studio Community edition. I can only make it work in Replit with the chevrons manually typed, but even then it only seems to work half of the time.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The chevrons are part of the python command line, not something that appears in a text file.

Comment: Don't confuse Python scripts (text files) and interactive IPython inputs through command line interface...

Comment: It sounds like you're running a script, not typing into a prompt the way the book assumes.  In a script if you want to print the result of an expression, you need to use the `print` function, e.g. `print(2+2)`.

Comment: @Samwise That seems to make the most sense. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please **carefully re-read** the description **before** that code example. After starting Mu, the tutorial tells you to "Click the New button and save an empty file as blank.py.". Did you do that? Then it says "When you run this blank file by clicking the Run button or pressing F5, it will open the interactive shell, which will open as a new pane that opens at the bottom of the Mu editor’s window.". Did you do either of those things (click the Run button or press F5)? When you do that, do you see that pane appear at the bottom of the window? Do you see the `>>>` in that pane?

Comment: (Just to make sure: did you try clicking to make sure that pane is active? Did you try typing in the code `2 + 2`? When you did that, did you see that text showing up **beside the `>>>`**? A programming book can teach programming; but it has to assume you understand a few things about using a computer, and it can't look over your shoulder to make sure you've done it properly.)